# How to get most significant n bits from int in java

Tags: java, caching, bit-manipulation

I have an int, and I would like to get the 19 most significant bits in java. I tried all sorts of methods, none of them work.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: I want to calculate the tag part of an address for a direct mapped cache implementation in java. So i need to compare the tag part of the cache line with the tag part of the address. the address is given as an int. I want to get the 19 most significant bits of that address (19 is the number of bits in the tag).

Comment: how do you want to represent these bits? as a binary string? What about the sign bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the 32 bit int, you want to keep the 19 most significant, so discard the 13 least; then you shift right by 13 bits, but have to get rid of the possible sign extension, by anding with a 19 bit pattern:

```
(myint >> 13) & 0x7ffff
```

Comment: Indeed, unsigned shift is also a good solution: myint >>> 13.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Bram's answer, you don't even need the `AND` if you use unsigned shift.

`myInt >>> 13;` will give you the 19MSB (although they're now situated in the lowest bits).

Answer (score 0):

Integer is of 4 byte i.e. 4*8 = 32 bits. So if you want to get 19th bit, you may want to try something like:

```
 if (myint & 0X00002000 >> 19 == 1) {
     //do something
 }
```

Comment: and to get all the 19 bits most significant bits?

Comment: remove the right shift and you have all 19 most significant bits