# int to short with two most significant bytes

Tags: java, int, short

I have an integer

```
int a = //...
```

`int`s in java consist of 4 bytes. If we cast it to `short`, we will take two least significant bytes. What is the fastest way to get `short` consisting of 2 most significant `byte`s of the `int`?

```
short b = //take two most significant bytes of a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get most significant n bits from int in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876549/how-to-get-most-significant-n-bits-from-int-in-java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
short b = (short) (a >> 16);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is sufficient to use the right bit shift operator (`>>`). Because the `int` primitive data type has the size of 32 bits ([Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) and you need to get the 16 most significant bits, it is necessary to perform the right bit shift by 16 bits:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int input = 0xABCDEFAB;
        final short output = (short) (input >> 16);
        System.out.printf("Original integer: %X%n", input);
        System.out.printf("Short with two most significant bytes: %X%n", output);
    }
}
```

Also, it is worth noting that the Java language has signed (`<<`, `>>`) and unsigned (`<<<`, `>>>`) bit shift operators. Please refer to the article: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

The same result can be produced using the division operator:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int input = 0xABCDEFAB;
        final short output = (short) (input / 0x10000);
        System.out.printf("Original integer: %X%n", input);
        System.out.printf("Short with two most significant bytes: %X%n", output);
    }
}
```